# Kafka through CNAMEs/load balancer when using Kerberos?

Tags: dns, apache-kafka, load-balancing, kerberos

I'm mainly looking for advice here around Kafka and disaster recovery failover.
Is there any way to use **Kafka** through **CNAMEs/load balancer** when using **Kerberos**?

When trying it, I get the below SPN error. This makes sense and I would fully expect this behaviour.
The only way I could picture this working would be to include a CNAME resolver into the Java client code before establishing a connection:

```
#Using the New Consumer API
#On any new connections, do the following:
1) Provide CNAME hostname in config
2) Resolve CNAME to list of A records for broker hosts
3) Pass these into the New Consumer as the bootstrap servers
```

This should work, however it would involve custom code.

The same concept applies for publishing to a topic.

Are there any ideas that might work without having to resort to this?

*I am using CDH 5 with Cloudera-managed keytab distribution.*

---

*Consumer log*

```
17/03/01 14:12:06 DEBUG consumer.KafkaConsumer: Subscribed to topic(s): build_smoke_test
17/03/01 14:12:06 DEBUG clients.NetworkClient: Initiating connection to node -1 at lb.cdh-poc-cluster.internal.cdhnetwork:9093.
17/03/01 14:12:06 DEBUG authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator: Set SASL client state to SEND_HANDSHAKE_REQUEST
17/03/01 14:12:06 DEBUG authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator: Creating SaslClient: client=alex@CDH-POC-CLUSTER.INTERNAL.CDHNETWORK;service=kafka;serviceHostname=lb.cdh-poc-cluster.internal.cdhnetwork;mechs=[GSSAPI]
17/03/01 14:12:06 DEBUG network.Selector: Connection with lb.cdh-poc-cluster.internal.cdhnetwork/172.3.1.10 disconnected
java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.read(SslTransportLayer.java:488)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:81)
```

*Broker log*

```
2017-03-01 14:12:08,330 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslServerAuthenticator: Set SASL server state to HANDSHAKE_REQUEST
2017-03-01 14:12:08,330 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslServerAuthenticator: Handle Kafka request SASL_HANDSHAKE
2017-03-01 14:12:08,330 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslServerAuthenticator: Using SASL mechanism 'GSSAPI' provided by client
2017-03-01 14:12:08,331 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslServerAuthenticator: Creating SaslServer for kafka/kf0.cdh-poc-cluster.internal.cdhnetwork@CDH-POC-CLUSTER.INTERNAL.CDHNETWORK with mechanism GSSAPI
2017-03-01 14:12:08,331 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslServerAuthenticator: Set SASL server state to AUTHENTICATE
2017-03-01 14:12:08,334 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslServerAuthenticator: Set SASL server state to FAILED
2017-03-01 14:12:08,334 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector: Connection with lb.cdh-poc-cluster.internal.cdhnetwork/172.3.1.10 disconnected
java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Checksum failed)]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslServerAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslServerAuthenticator.java:243)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:64)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:318)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:283)
    at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:472)
    at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:412)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Checksum failed)]
    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Server.evaluateResponse(GssKrb5Server.java:199)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslServerAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslServerAuthenticator.java:228)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a SPN registered against your CNAME (and if not, might that also be a solution)?

Comment: Please reword your answer. It can easily be read as pure question. In other words: make it more clear that you have a proposal how to solve the problem.